# How to install openssl from Python using os?

Tags: python, openssl

I need to run several shell commands from Python. Everything works fine except the command shown below.

```
import os
exec_r = os.system("apt-get install libssl-dev")
```

In logs I see the following message:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl-doc libssl1.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.1
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 4431 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

It seems that I need to integrate the auto answering into the shell command.

```
exec_r = os.system("apt-get install libssl-dev y")
```

Then I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package y
```

Comment: From apt manual you need to run apt-get -y install libssl-dev